# Running Cypher queries on the entire db

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of 2 types of entities, Author and Reference, and they are connected from A ->R by 'Authored' type. Someone helped me come up with this code to add a new set of relationships

```
match (a)-[r]->(b)<-[r2]-(c)
merge (a)-[new:CoAuthor]->(c)
on create set new.weight=1
on match set new.weight=new.weight+1
```

However, I keep running out of memory. I tried limiting the number of times this would execute with the following code:

```
start a=node(1)
match (a)-[r:Authored]->(b)<-[r2:Authored]-(c)
with a
limit 10
match (b)<-[r2]-(c)
create (a)-[new:CoAuthor]->(c);
```

But still no luck, even with maximum memory set at 3072m. Is there a way to iterate through the entire DB and have this done in stages in the background? I cannot manually do this 10 nodes at a time b/c I have something like 600k authors and 1.5m references and 7m relationships between them.

This is going to be a one time write, as this is not a transactional db. The intent is to create these links to support the real querying I need to do later. I also have other entities that I need to put in the db, and was hoping I could identify an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one (keep running until you get 0 back from the count; might try increasing to 10000 if 1000 goes fast enough):

```
match (a)-[r:Authored]->(b)<-[r2:Authored]-(c)
where NOT (a)-[:CoAuthor]-(c)
with a, c
limit 1000
create unique (a)-[new:CoAuthor]-(c)
return count(*)
```

Then, if you want to count the number of books they worked on together, I would do that in a followup query. It's hard to create unique undirected relationships at the moment.

```
match (a)-[r:CoAuthor]-(b)
with length((a)-[:Authored]->()<-[:Authored]-(b)) as count, r
set r.weight=count
```

Might require some batching as well if you've got a lot of data, but give it a try.

Comment: The first idea is working, although a bit labor intensive. I hadn't meant to try to insert an undirected edge; instead I was hoping to find a moderately decent solution and then insert a directed edge heading in the opposite direction. I'll let you know if the second solution offered works. TYVM

Comment: If you want it to be directed, do you want two edges for each pair of authors?

Comment: Not particularly as it is not normally considered to be a directed relationship. However, I thought I had read that Neo4j handles directed relationships more effectively.

Comment: Neo4j always stores relationships in a directed way, but if you create unique  without a direction it will only create one relationship (because it matches either direction), rather than two.

Comment: okay. is there a way to select the first x nodes, if there is no id property?